# CUDA Kernel function for parsing a packet with variable number of messages

Tags: cuda

I am new to CUDA and I am trying to write a efficient kernel function for parsing a packet containing 'k' different messages each of different length (which I know). This is what I have done.

```
//head ----> pointing to a page locked memory i.e start of the packet
//k -----> Number of messages in the packet

host_func()
{
    cudaHostGetDevicePointer(&d_dataPtr, head, 0);

    int *h_bytes;
    cudaHostAlloc((void**)&h_bytes, sizeof(int), cudaHostAllocWriteCombined | cudaHostAllocMapped);
    *h_bytes = 0;
    cudaHostGetDevicePointer(&d_bytes, h_bytes, 0);

    kernel<<<1,26>>>(d_dataPtr, d_bytes, k);
    cudaThreadSynchronize();
}
__global__ void kernel(char *data, int *bytesProcessed, int *numOfMessages)
{
    int temp = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<*numOfMessages;i++)
    {
        switch(*data)
        {
            case 'A':
            //do some processing
            temp = sizeof(MessageA);
            break;

            case 'B':
            //do some processing
            temp = sizeof(MessageB);
            break;

            case 'C':
            //do some processing
            temp = sizeof(MessageB);
            break;
        }
        data += temp;
        *bytesProcessed += temp;
    }
}
```

I am able to parse the data but the problem is the threads in same warp are processing the same message type which makes this kernel highly inefficient. Any help in synchronizing the threads properly would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have an actual question to ask? I don't see one.....

Comment: what do you mean by I dont see? I am having a difficulty writing a cuda kernel function

Comment: I mean that you have not asked a question anywhere in what you have posted. Please edit your post so it contains a concise, answerable question and someone might be able to help you. Some guidelines on asking questions on stackoverflow can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: ok i got your point, i will edit the question

Comment: @Juggernaut Your kernel is inefficient (for at least one reason) because it creates only one block of 26 CUDA threads. The scale of parallelism necessary to efficiently utilize a GPU is on the order of hundreds of thousands of CUDA threads.

Comment: @Juggernaut ```*bytesProcessed += temp``` is also a race condition. Moreover, your kernel does not depend on ```blockIdx``` or ```threadIdx```, which means that your 26 threads all perform the same computation, bashing each other's (identical) results.

Comment: @JaredHoberock i dont understand how should I use blockIdx or threadIdx as I dont know the next message in the packet.

Comment: @Juggernaut: This seems like an inherently serial operation that will be a very poor fit for the GPU architecture. You might be best served by "preprocessing" the message stream in the host CPU first to make it easier to parallelise on the GPU.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make a CUDA program efficient, you often need to invent new algorithms. Just copying a good CPU program onto GPU does not make it faster (it may even make it slower!).
One of key components is that certain parts of the algorithm can work in parallel and on independent data. Image processing or linear algebra often fall into that category.

Secondly, there must be a lot of computation to be done. Just few conditions and simple arithmetic won't do it - you will pay much more for transferring the data to GPU, than you will gain from faster processing.

In parsing or stream processing (unless this is a video stream) I don't see these properties anywhere. The meaning of the next byte of your input depends heavily on the information you have already read.

If you can change the communication protocol, you could try opening *several* connections at once, and read independent data from there. But there still needs to be a lot of computation involved on the GPU, otherwise it is not worth it.